# Split in Columns String in Java

Tags: java, string

I have this String in Java:

```
String productLine="1.00 REFRESCO COLA 1.20 1.20";
```

i need to split it in columns to get:

```
String amount="1.00";
String product="REFRESCO COLA";
String unitPrice="1.20";
String total="1.20"
```

how can I do it? 
the product can have more than one space or amount can have 3 zeros or none, it can be:

```
String lineProduct="1.000' CAÑA DE CERVEZA 0.0 1.20 1.20";
String amount="1.00";
String product="CAÑA DE CERVEZA 0.0";
String unitPrice="1.20";
String total="1.20"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String[] split = productLine.split(" ");
String amount="split[0];
String product = "";
for(int i = 0: i < split.length-3; i++){ 
     if(i > 0 ){ //adding spaces
         product = product + " ";
     }
     product = product + split[i+1];
}
String unitPrice=split[split.length-2];
String total=split[split.length-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in method split (char), which creates an array of the new strings. However, since the provided name of product will contain spaces, you'll want to replace the spaces in the product with underscores before running the entire thing through the split function.